# How can I remove all instances/custom objects created of one class?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need some help with JavaScript and Google Maps API.

I have a Google Maps map on my website which shows markers, which in turn show a custom `InfoBox` when clicked on.

When a marker is clicked, a new object is created for this `InfoBox`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoBox = new InfoBox({id: id, content: description, latlng: marker.getPosition(), map: map});
});
```

When a visitor clicks two markers consecutively, he is faced with two `InfoBox`s. I run two lines of code that hide the `InfoBox`s when a users clicks away in the map or when they click the cross in the upper right corner:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeImg, 'click', removeInfoBox(this));
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', removeInfoBox(this));
```

What I would like to happen is that when a user clicks on a marker, all previous markers will get hidden (so after each click on a marker, there would only be one previous `InfoBox` to be hidden).

I'm struggling to get this done. If I create a `DomListener` on all markers with the 'click' event, I never get an `InfoBox` to pop up. If I put `removeInfoBox(this);` before creating a new object of `InfoBox` I also never get shown an `InfoBox`.

Where and how would be the proper way to prevent more than one `InfoBox` from showing up?

Comment: Javascript does not have classes.

Answer (score 4):

I found a post on how to remove markers and keep track of them which I could adept to my script.

First I declare the array for storing opened infoBox'es and the function to remove them (clearOverlays()):

```
// Declare global array for hiding infowindows
var infowindowsArray = [];

function clearOverlays(){
    if(infowindowsArray){
        for (i in infowindowsArray){
            infowindowsArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I create a listener for the marker's click event, it will add the new infoBox to that marker. First I use the clearOverlays() function to clear all other infoBox'es. Then I create the new infoBox and push it into the array:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    clearOverlays();
    infoBox = new InfoBox({id: id, content: description, latlng: marker.getPosition(), map: map});
    infowindowsArray.push(infoBox);
});
```

This solved my problem with the custom created infoBox'es.